# Center of a rectangle after rotation and shifting in Javascript, Raphael.FreeTransform

Tags: javascript, raphael, center

I have a problem with Raphael.Freetransform. I need the coordinates of the four corners of a rectangle. Unfortunately it is not possible to simply use the x,y,width and height attributes of the rectangle after a transformation, because they still have the data of before.

With rectangle.matrix.x(x,y) and rectangle.matrix.y(x,y) I can receive the real x and y coordinates of the top left corner and with rectangle.attrs.scale.x and rectangle.attrs.scale.y I can calculate the changed width and height of the rectangle.

Now I do need the center coordinates of the transformed and shifted rectangle to calculate with the help of the rotation angle the other corners, but unfortunately the rectangle.attrs.center.x function of Raphael.FreeTransform only returns the initial center of the rectangle.

So how can I get the coordinates of the center of the rotated and shifted rectangle?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the local coordinate system of the element, the center is at x+width/2, y+height/2, under the assumption that the rectangle goes from (x,y) to (x+width, y+height). So you have to find the coordinates in the global system using the matrix functions.

Comment: Aaaahh.. now I have calculated the four corners of the rectangle before transformation and got the real data after transformation by using the matrix.x(x,y) with the corner coordinates.
Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as fine as I thought. The matrix.x(x,y) and matrix.y(x,y) functions do only return the true coordinates of the corners as long as the rectangle is not rotated for more than 45°. Otherwise the x- and y-coordinates of the single corners mix up and suddenly the y-coordinate of the former upper left corner is swapped with the y-coordinate of the former lower left corner, for example.
Do you have any ideas what could be done here?
Thank you in advance!